# Global variable value thread safe inside Runnable implementation?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

I am seeing this behavior where I have my own implementation of Runnable interface and global variable value remains thread safe in several of my tests.

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

private String taskName;

private int executeCount = new Random().nextInt(10);

public MyRunnable(String taskName) {
    this.taskName = taskName;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println(this.taskName + " in Thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ". execute count: " + ++executeCount);
}
}
```

I start off 10 threads and run my code concurrently. Somehow, value of `executeCount` remains safe and I see expected value.

Is this a blip? Every time I run the test and it just happen to be printing correct values but in reality it is not safe? Or the behavior is expected?

This is my thead start:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class DynamicSchedularApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DynamicSchedularApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler ts = threadPoolTaskScheduler();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ts.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyRunnable("Task"+i),
            Duration.ofMillis(3000));
    }
}

@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler ts = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    ts.setPoolSize(10);
    return ts;
}

}
```

Comment: How is this a global variable? It is not static and you are scheduling  new instance of your runnable each loop tick.

Comment: @michalk by global he wants to say it's visible anywhere in that object(i think). Also I don't see any reason to not be safe.

Comment: As you are creating a new instance of `MyRunnable` for each thread this is thread safe. It would be different if you would have a single instance and shared it across those 10 threads.

Comment: Thank you @M.Deinum. One thing that was confusing to me was that one Task/MyRunnable instance would run on different threads (identified by Thread ID). So I was confused how could this be. But Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As every thread has it's own `executeCount` which is non-static and every thread accesses just it's own `executeCount`, you program is thread safe. It doesn't matter that you are implementing `Runnable`, what matters is the scope of the variable and from where it is accessed.